# How can I best generate a static array of random number on demand?

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

An application I'm working on requires a matrix of random numbers. The matrix can grow in any direction at any time, and isn't always full. (I'll probably end up re-implementing it with a quad tree or something else, rather than a matrix with a lot of null objects.)

I need a way to generate the same matrix, given the same seed, no matter in which order I calculate the matrix.

```
LazyRandomMatrix rndMtx1 = new LazyRandomMatrix(1234) // Seed new object
float X = rndMtx1[0,0] // Lazily generate random numbers on demand
float Y = rndMtx1[3,16]
float Z = rndMtx1[23,-5]

Debug.Assert(X == rndMtx1[0,0])
Debug.Assert(Y == rndMtx1[3,16])
Debug.Assert(Z == rndMtx1[23,-5])

LazyRandomMatrix rndMtx2 = new LazyRandomMatrix(1234) // Seed second object
Debug.Assert(Y == rndMtx2[3,16])  // Lazily generate the same random numbers
Debug.Assert(Z == rndMtx2[23,-5]) // on demand in a different order
Debug.Assert(X == rndMtx2[0,0])
```

Yes, if I knew the dimensions of the array, the best way would be to generate the entire array, and just return values, but they need to be generated independently and on demand.

My first idea was to initialize a new random number generator for each call to a new coordinate, seeding it with some hash of the overall matrix's seed and the coordinates used in calling, but this seems like a terrible hack, as it would require creating a ton of new `Random` objects.

Comment: Is the quality of the randomness important to you? So is it important that the numbers have a good "random" distribution?

Comment: I would like that the random numbers have a similar distribution to generating the array statically (a big `for` loop with known dimensions in the constructor). Basically, the best (though obviously impossible) solution would to be to generate an infinite matrix of random numbers when you create the object, and simply return whatever value is asked for.

Comment: That is going to be tough. I am not aware of a random number generator that allows you to randomly access the random sequence (there might be one though) a pseudo random number generator generates numbers in a sequence. What it sounds like you want to do is pick a random number from the sequence based on the index into the matrix, the problem as you have seen is that you then need to pregenerate the entire sequence. Best alternative I can think of is to go for a weak prng which generates a number based on the index and the seed, distribution won't be great...

Comment: "similar"? - I never heard about that distribution. :) But you can convert some distributions through applying some function (which changed density at some places) to result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're talking about is typically called "Perlin Noise", here's a link for you: http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm

The most important thing in that article is the noise function in 2D:

```
  function Noise1(integer x, integer y)
    n = x + y * 57
    n = (n<<13) ^ n;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);    
  end function
```

It returns a number between -1.0 and +1.0 based on the x and y coordonates alone (and a hard coded seed that you can change randomly at the start of your app or just leave it as it is).

The rest of the article is about interpolating these numbers, but depending on how random you want these numbers, you can just leave them as it is. Note that these numbers will be utterly random. If you instead apply a Cosine Interpolator and use the generated noise every 5-6 indexes, interpolating inbetween, you get heightmap data (which is what I used it for). Skip it for totally random data.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to generate Perlin Noise. The examples I had seen from it all generated the Noise function in an array during construction. Are those all just magic numbers in a custom hash function?

Comment: @Blindy - Your function isn't exactly what is typically called Perlin Noise.  Perlin Noise involves iterating over it multiple times, with a different wavelength and amplitude.  But it does exactly give the asker what he wants.

Comment: @Blindy - To build off what Justin said - Like you said "these numbers will be utterly random." Perlin Noise typically has filters applied to it, making it not completely random, so that it behaves like height maps or smoke distribution or something of the sort.

Comment: Perlin noise shows a lot of correlation between nearby points, though. Is that what you want, Daniel, or do you want each point to be entirely independent of its neighbours?

Comment: @Justin - Sorry, I just realized you're the same person who answered my previous question. No need to point you there... *facepalm*

Comment: Well yea if you go through the extra step of smoothing out the noise and adding extra amplitudes together, you get a smoother output. But the basis of Perlin Noise is the noise function, which is what i wrote above! And to answer your first comment Daniel, there is no need to hold the generated values in an array, the function will always return the same values for the same inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Standart random generator usually is generator of sequence, where each next element is build from previous. So to generate `rndMtx1[3,16]` you have to generate all previous elements in a sequence.
Actually you need something different from random *generator*, because you need only one value, but not the sequence. You have to build your own "generator" which uses seed and indexes as input for formula to produce single random value. You can invent many ways to do so. One of the simplest way is to take random value asm `hash(seed + index)` (I guess idea of hashes used in passwords and signing is to produce some stable "random" value out of input data).

P.S. You can improve your approach with independent generators (`Random(seed + index)`) by making lazy blocks of matrix.

Comment: How random is a `hash` of similar integers going to be? I was considering lazy blocks to improve the `Random(seed + index)` method, but I still think there has to be a better way.

Comment: @Daniel, good hash functions should try to produce [uniform-distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Uniformity) hashes. So using them for non-random data should produce uniform distributed value. After that you can transform it to some other distributions.

Answer (score 2):

I think your first idea of instantiating a new Random object seeded by some deterministic hash of (x-coordinate, y-coordinate, LazyRandomMatrix seed) is probably reasonable for most situations. In general, creating lots of small objects on the managed heap is something the CLR is very good at handling efficiently. And I don't think Random.ctor() is terribly expensive. You can easily measure the performance if it's a concern.

A very similar solution which may be easier than creating a good deterministic hash is to use two Random objects each time. Something like:

```
public int this[int x, int y]
{
    get
    {
        Random r1 = new Random(_seed * x);
        Random r2 = new Random(y);
        return (r1.Next() ^ r2.Next());
    }
}
```

Comment: Or even, new Random(_seed * x ^ y).

Comment: Would this produce a better distribution than simply hashing `seed ^ x ^ y`? (`seed * x ^ y` seems like it could overflow if my coordinates were high enough...)

Comment: @Daniel: As long as you're not using checked math (see checked keyword or the C# compiler's checked keyword), overflows should be okay since the result will just be the low-order bits that fit. The overflowing bits will be ignored.

Comment: @DonaldRay: I used the 2 Random objects simply because it seemed easier to avoid uneven distributions or weird patterns. For example, (_seed * x ^ y) doesn't vary with _seed when x == 0. That is lazy[0, 1] would produce the same result regarless of _seed.

Comment: Most RNGs produce similar outputs for similar seeds, so this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

[PRNGs can be built out of hash functions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Use_in_building_other_cryptographic_primitives)
This is what e.g. MS Research did with parallelizing random number generation [with MD5](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70502/tr-2007-141.ppt)   or [others with TEA](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/~olano/papers/GPUTEA.pdf) on a GPU.
(In fact, PRNGs can be thought of as a hash function from (seed, state) => nextnumber.)
Generating massive amounts of random numbers on a GPU brings up similar problems.
(E.g., to make it parallel, there should not be a single shared state.)

Although it is more common in the crypto world, using a crypto hash, I have taken the liberty to use [MurmurHash 2.0](http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/) for sake of speed and simplicity. It has very good statistical properties as a hash function. A related, but not identical test shows that it gives [good results](http://www.serice.net/flawed_hash_functions/) as a PRNG. (unless I have fsc#kd up something in the C# code, that is.:) Feel free to use any other suitable hash function; crypto ones (MD5, TEA, SHA) as well - though crypto hashes tend to be much slower.

```
public class LazyRandomMatrix
{
    private uint seed;

    public LazyRandomMatrix(int seed)
    {
        this.seed = (uint)seed;
    }

    public int this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            return MurmurHash2((uint)x, (uint)y, seed);
        }
    }

    static int MurmurHash2(uint key1, uint key2, uint seed)
    {
        // 'm' and 'r' are mixing constants generated offline.
        // They're not really 'magic', they just happen to work well.

        const uint m = 0x5bd1e995;
        const int r = 24;

        // Initialize the hash to a 'random' value

        uint h = seed ^ 8;

        // Mix 4 bytes at a time into the hash

        key1 *= m;
        key1 ^= key1 >> r;
        key1 *= m;

        h *= m;
        h ^= key1;

        key2 *= m;
        key2 ^= key2 >> r;
        key2 *= m;

        h *= m;
        h ^= key2;

        // Do a few final mixes of the hash to ensure the last few
        // bytes are well-incorporated.

        h ^= h >> 13;
        h *= m;
        h ^= h >> 15;

        return (int)h;
    }

}
```

Comment: Will negative values mess up the MurmurHash2? What if I wanted it to take two floats?

Comment: @Daniel: No, they won't.
The link above to Murmur 2 shows that it takes a sequence of bytes. Since everything can be converted to a sequence of bytes, the original accepts everything. I just tried to simplify the original somewhat for your case. A C# implementation can be found on Murmur's wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on a SHA1 hash. Basically this takes the bytes for the X, Y and Seed values and packs this into a byte array. Then a hash for the byte array and the first 4 bytes of the hash used to generate an `int`. This should be pretty random.

```
public class LazyRandomMatrix 
{
  private int _seed;
  private SHA1 _hashProvider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

  public LazyRandomMatrix(int seed)
  {
    _seed = seed;
  }

  public int this[int x, int y]
  {
    get
    {
      byte[] data = new byte[12];
      Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 0, data, 0, 4);
      Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(y), 0, data, 4, 4);
      Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(_seed), 0, data, 8, 4);

      byte[] hash = _hashProvider.ComputeHash(data);
      return BitConverter.ToInt32(hash, 0);
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: More than 'pretty' random. :)

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo-random number generator is essentially a function that deterministically calculates a successor for a given value.

You could invent a simple algorithm that calculates a value from its neighbours. If a neighbour doesn't have a value yet, calculate its value from its respective neighbours first.

Something like this:

- value<sub>(0,0)</sub> = seed
- value<sub>(x+1,0)</sub> = successor(value<sub>(x,0)</sub>)
- value<sub>(x,y+1)</sub> = successor(value<sub>(x,y)</sub>)

Example with *successor(n) = n+1* to calculate value<sub>(2,4)</sub>:

```
 \ x  0      1      2
y  +-------------------
 0 | 627    628    629
 1 |               630
 2 |               631
 3 |               632
 4 |               633
```

This example algorithm is obviously not very good, but you get the idea.

Comment: I was just going to suggest using a quasi-monte carlo, but changed my mind.  But seeing your post, I think quasi-random is the way to go.

Comment: A good suggestion, but as I said, they should be generated "independently and on demand." So if I need to get value(100,100), I don't want to calculate 200 successors before I get to the one I want.

Comment: @Daniel Rasmussen: If you deterministically want to generate the same matrix for the same seed value, and don't want the values to be purely based on the indices, I believe there is no other way than to calculate all intermediary values for a given index pair.

Comment: Yeah, that's great idea for moving character over random world (i.e. when you move one cell at a time). But you still have to generate sequence for random-accessed value.

Comment: I'm assuming the draw here is that it will provide a much more equal distribution than using nothing but the index? In all fairness, this would probably work just fine, as I'm doing exactly what ony said - a moving character over random world, and most likely won't have to jump so far as to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want a random number generator with random access to the elements, instead of sequential access. (Note that you can reduce your two coordinates into a single index i.e. by computing i = x + (y << 16).)

A cool example of such a generator is [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_blum_shub), which is a cryptographically secure PRNG with easy random-access. Unfortunately, it is very slow.

A more practical example is the well-known linear congruential generator. You can easily modify one to allow random access. Consider the definition:

```
X(0) = S
X(n) = B + X(n-1)*A (mod M)
```

Evaluating this directly would take O(n) time (that's [pseudo linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time), not linear), but you can convert to a non-recursive form:

```
//Expand a few times to see the pattern:
X(n) = B + X(n-1)*A (mod M)
X(n) = B + (B + X(n-2)*A)*A (mod M)
X(n) = B + (B + (B + X(n-3)*A)*A)*A (mod M)
//Aha! I see it now, and I can reduce it to a closed form:
X(n) = B + B*A + B*A*A + ... + B*A^(N-1) + S*A^N (mod M)
X(n) = S*A^N + B*SUM[i:0..n-1](A^i) (mod M)
X(n) = S*A^N + B*(A^N-1)/(A-1) (mod M)
```

That last equation can be computed relatively quickly, although the second part of it is a bit tricky to get right (because division doesn't distribute over mod the same way addition and multiplication do).

Comment: +1 for the excellent explanation of linear generator and expanding it to a non-recursive form.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, there are 2 basic algorithms possible here:

- Generate a new random number based on `func(seed, coord)` for each coord
- Generate a single random number from seed, and then transform it for the coord (something like `rotate(x) + translate(y)` or whatever)

In the first case, you have the problem of always generating new random numbers, although this may not be as expensive as you fear.

In the second case, the problem is that you may lose randomness during your transformation operations. However, in either case the result is reproducible.