# (P)RNG - Array of Random Numbers Created with a Seed

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I want to create an array of random/pseudo-random numbers using a seed. I want the very same array to be created when the same seed is used and I want to have little or no visible pattern in the array. I'm working in JavaScript.

This is the random function I'm using, which I'm quite happy with (sorry, I forgot who the original author is):

```
function random(seed) {
    if (!seed) seed = new Date().getTime();
    seed = (seed*9301+49297) % 233280;
    return seed/(233280.0);
}
```

This is the array generation:

```
var superSeed = random();
var nRandom = 100;
var randomArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0 ; i < nRandom ; i++){
    randomArray.push(random((superSeed*10)+ (i)));
}
```

Somehow the pattern seems to be quite similar, no matter how often I run it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134759/how-can-i-best-generate-a-static-array-of-random-number-on-demand) seems to be similar, but since it's about matrixes, I don't understand what's being said.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't quite on topic for your question, but it looks like you're using the Central Randomizer, which was created way back in 1997 when browsers didn't have good built-in randomization functions. One should generally use Math.random() now, although for your specific question here you probably won't use it since you really are looking for pseudo-random.

Comment: Just a note: **pseudo-random** If you're using a seed there's no way they can be random.

Comment: As for why your algorithm doesn't look very random:  seed should be a global static variable, not a local variable.  The way you have it now, you are just adding a constant amount (9301/233280) to the previous "random" value each iteration.  You should only have to seed a random-number generator once, not every time you call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked on similar things before I think we can use a fairly simple series, which takes two initial values and then you can get a lot more.

```
var a1,b1;

function InitSequence(v1, v2) {
    a1 = Math.pow(v1, 5) / Math.pow(v1, 3);
    b1 = Math.pow(v2, 8);
    lastrand = (a1 + b1) & 0x7fffffff;
}

function SequenceNext() {
    var alast = a1;
    var nextVal = (a1 + b1) & 0x7fffffff;
    b1 = alast;
    a1 = nextVal;
    return nextVal;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
InitSequence(75, 21);
for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    v = SequenceNext();
}
```

I tested it like this:

```
var used = new Array();

InitSequence(75, 21); // any two values will do.

// fill 10k into array.

for (var i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
    v = SequenceNext();
    if (undefined != used[v]) {
        used[v]++;
    } else used[v] = 1;

    //document.write(i+": "+v+"<br>");
}

// see if there any duplicates.
var tdup = 0;
for (xx in used) {
    ndup = used[xx];
    if (ndup > 1) {
        document.write("duplicated " + xx + " :" + ndup + "<br>");
        tdup += ndup;
    }
}
document.write("Total dups " + tdup + "<br>");
```

---

This is using the [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)  series, which in mathematical terms, the sequence Fn of [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) numbers is defined by the recurrence relation
[image: Fibonacci recurrence relation]. I'm starting with different values - (v1^5) / (v1^3) and v2 ^ 8; otherwise it would only ever be identical.

Comment: Sweeeeet! Thanks :) Is that "x + (y*57)? Or "(x+y)*57"?

Comment: javascript order of precedence is standard so it's x + (y * 57). ps you normally say thanks by upvoting or accepting answers. see the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Apparently Photoshop's JavaScript engine doesn't like the "& 7fffffff" and gives me "Error 25: Expected: )." for that line. I don't understand that part anyway.

Comment: Okay, I replaced "7fffffff" with "0x7fffffff" and that seems to be working fine. But now pretty much all the numbers I get are 1.

Comment: I'll fix this and post a revision shortly.

Comment: Thanks! That's... wow.... I'm having the hardest time grasping what each segment does ^^ That's specifically to create Perlin noise?

Comment: The revised method uses the Fibonacci series - any integer sequence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sequence) would do. It's not Perlin noise anymore - that was my bad idea... Hopefully this one should work for you. Let me know if you've got any more questions...

Answer (score 2):

I like the "Super 7" PRNG. It is simple, fast (although the other answer with the fib. sequence is fast as well), and has the interesting property:

- In the entire range -- albeit of a meager of 32k -- *there are no duplicates* using the "Super 7" PRNG.

Multiple 7's can be joined to increase the number of bits and/or provide multiple seeds. This non-duplication property can exposed or folded.

(The sequence of a PRNG is always the same given a starting seed: it's the distribution and cycle lengths that are interesting -- it is these properties that may make them ideal in different cases where "true randomness" isn't desired).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this

`function s_random() {
  s_random.m = 71402523; s_random.a = 409647; s_random.c = 1508892;
  s_random.seed = (s_random.seed*s_random.a + s_random.c) % s_random.m;
  return s_random.seed / s_random.m;
}
/* 
generate IV
s_random.seed = Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/10000);
*/
s_random.seed = 130324232;`

var CheckRandom  = 4999999;
var PrintSamples = 100;
var used = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < CheckRandom; i++) {
    v = (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(s_random())* 1000000000) * 8);
    if (undefined != used[v]) {
        used[v]++;
    } else used[v] = 1;
    if ( i< PrintSamples) document.write(i+": "+v+"
");
}
/* see if there are any duplicates. */
var tdup = 0;
for (xx in used) {
    ndup = used[xx];
    if (ndup > 1) {
        if (ndup < PrintSamples) document.write("duplicated " + xx + " :" + ndup + "
");
        tdup += ndup;
    }
}
document.write("Total generated  " + CheckRandom + "
");
document.write("Total duplicates " + tdup + "
");

Just got 5 million seeded, repeatable random numbers and no duplicates. Tested several times on Mac OS X with Safari.

Cheers,
Karl